# Nested loops output to dict in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, concurrent.futures

I have two set of data:

```
aDict = {'barcode1': [('barcode1', 184), ('barcode1_mut', 2)], 'barcode2': [('barcode2', 138)], 'barcode3': [('barcode3', 375)]}
bList = [(('barcode1', 'mut1'), 184), (('barcode1_mut', 'mut2'), 2), (('barcode2', 'mut3'), 136), (('barcode2', 'mut4'), 1), (('barcode2', 'mut5'), 1), (('barcode3', 'mut6'), 373), (('barcode3', 'mut7'), 2)]
```

And i'm matching for every keys in dict **aDict** with barcode in list **bList** and result:

```
>>>print(result)
{'barcode1': {'barcode1': [('mut1', 184)], 'barcode1_mut': [('mut2', 2)]},
'barcode2': {'barcode2': [('mut3', 136), ('mut4', 1), ('mut5', 1)]},
'barcode3': {'barcode3': [('mut6', 373), ('mut7', 2)]}}
```

But it's too slow for me. I tried paralleling the code with the output of information on the number of processed lines. But in my implementation, each line is processed simultaneously by all workers.

Now, my implementation looks like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(uniqueBarcode):
    mutBarcodeList = [x[0] for x in aDict[uniqueBarcode]]
    a = filter(lambda x: x[0][0] in mutBarcodeList, bList.items())
    d = defaultdict(tuple)
    b = [(x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])) for x in a]
    for tup in b: d[tup[0]] += (tup[1],)
    result = {i[0]:[y for y in i[1]] for i in d.items()}
    return result

seqDict={}

if __name__=='__main__':
    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(cpus)
    for barcode in aDict.keys():
        seqDict[barcode] = pool.map(f, [barcode])
        if len(seqDict) % 100 == 0:
            print("Processed {} barcodes".format(len(seqDict)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output:

```
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 100 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
Processed 200 barcodes
...
```

And dict **seqDict** is empty, but it must not be so - the first line is processed by the first process, the second line is the second one ... the eighth is the eighth process, the ninth line is again the first process and etc.

How to do it in parallel correctly?

**Upd0:** I'm adapted Flomp's code to me

```
res={}
for key in aDict:
    if len(aDict[key]) == 1:
        res[key] = {key:[(a[1],b) for a,b in bList if a[0] == key]}
    elif len(aDict[key]) > 1:
        res[key] = {x[0]:[(a[1],b) for a,b in bList if a[0] == x[0]] for x in aDict[key]}
```

But it work so long

Comment: You may want to read [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, i'm editing my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: convert bList into dict.

```
bDict = {
('barcode1', 'mut1'): 184, 
('barcode1_mut', 'mut2'): 2, 
('barcode2', 'mut3'): 136, 
('barcode2', 'mut4'): 1, 
('barcode2', 'mut5'): 1, 
('barcode3', 'mut6'): 373, 
('barcode3', 'mut7'): 2}
```

Second: combine values with the same barcode.

```
mDict = {}
for x, y in bDict.items():
    if mDict.get(x[0]) == None:
        mDict[x[0]] = [(x[1], y)]
    else:
        mDict[x[0]].append((x[1], y))
>>>print(mDict)
{'barcode1': [('mut1', 184)],
'barcode1_mut': [('mut2', 2)],
'barcode2': [('mut3', 136), ('mut4', 1), ('mut5', 1)],
'barcode3': [('mut6', 373), ('mut7', 2)]}
```

Third: assign result to unique barcode.

```
seqDict = {x: {y[0]: mDict[y[0]] for y in aDict[x]} for x in aDict.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of for-loops in your code. This slows down your program. Here is some code with a better runtime:

```
bcDict = {'TTCTCTTACCGGGTAC':1,'ACCTCTCGAGAATTCA':2,'TGCAGTTCTGTGCATC':3}

bcMutCount = [(('TTCTCTTACCGGGTAC', 'ATTCAACA'), 184), 
(('ACCTCTCGAGAATTCA', 'CATCCCAC'), 136), 
(('ACCTCTCGAGAATTCA', 'CATGCCAC'), 1),
(('ACCTCTCGAGAATTCA', 'CATCCCCC'), 1),
(('TGCAGTTCTGTGCATC', 'TCTACATT'), 373),
(('TGCAGTTCTGTGCATC', 'ACTGCGCA'), 2)]


for key in bcDict:
  print({key:[(a[1],b) for a,b in bcMutCount if a[0] == key]})
```

Output:

```
{'TTCTCTTACCGGGTAC': [('ATTCAACA', 184)]}
{'ACCTCTCGAGAATTCA': [('CATCCCAC', 136), ('CATGCCAC', 1), ('CATCCCCC', 1)]}
{'TGCAGTTCTGTGCATC': [('TCTACATT', 373), ('ACTGCGCA', 2)]}
```

Please correct me if this is not what you want. The code above should run in *O(m*n)* where *m* is the number of keys in bcDict and *n* is the length of bcMutCount.
Does this run sufficiently fast?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'm edting post to minimal

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm sorry, I did not quite represent bcDict variable. In this dictionary, one key is mapped to a list of tuples, of which there can be more than one. Now I edited my question.

About speed: now I have ~380 000 keys in bcDict and ~10 000 000 items in bcMutCount :) And me as the air requires parallelization. Early I'm using multiprocessing.pool.map(function, bcDict.keys()), but this did not lead to an acceleration of the process. I have two implementations of parallel computations, but they work slowly. If necessary, I can add them to my question.